# Sign CSR from client using CA root certificate in python

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, ssl-certificate, m2crypto, pyopenssl

I am new to python and still learning it so my question can be little naive. Please bear with it ;)

The problem is client will be sending CSR and I want to sign it with my CA root certificate and return the signed certificate back to client.

I have been using this command to do it using command line

**openssl x509 -req -in device.csr -CA root.pem -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out device.crt -days 500**

same thing I want achieve using python. I have come across python library for openssl [pyopenssl](https://pythonhosted.org/pyOpenSSL/)

is it possible using this library ? How ? or shoudl I go for M2Crypto ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can indeed go with pyOpenSSL. As you are saying you already have CA root certificate and a private key, and CSR will be sent by a client then you can use functions of crypto to read all those ( CA cert, private key and Device CSR ) from file or manage to have them in buffer.

Use below functions to start with. Check `dir(crypto) and crypto.function_name.__doc__`on python interpreter for more info :) You need to import crypto from pyOpenSSL

1. crypto.load_certificate_request() - to get device CSR obj
2. crypto.load_privatekey() - to get private key obj for CA private key
3. crypto.load_certificate() - to get CA root certificate

then you can write simple funcation to return certificate

```
def create_cert():
    cert = crypto.X509()
    cert.set_serial_number(serial_no)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(notBeforeVal)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(notAfterVal)
    cert.set_issuer(caCert.get_subject())
    cert.set_subject(deviceCsr.get_subject())
    cert.set_pubkey(deviceCsr.get_pubkey())
    cert.sign(CAprivatekey, digest)
    return cert
```

where **caCert** , **deviceCsr** and **CAprivatekey** are values from above three funcations. 
Now that you have certificate with you, you can write this to a file using `crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)` with file name of your choice.

You can modify this function as per your requirement. After this you can verify generated device certificate with CA root certificate with openssl command e.g. `openssl verify -CApath <CA cert path>  <name of device cert file>`

You can also go through few examples from github. 
[M2Crypto Example](https://gist.github.com/eskil/2338529) , [pyOpenSSL example](https://github.com/msabramo/pyOpenSSL)

Hope this gives you idea about the implementation

Answer (score 12):

The maintainer of `pyOpenSSL` recommends to use `cryptography` module for X509 manipulation (see note on top of the documentation page: https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html).

Here is the code to create a certificate from a CSR signed by a CA:

```
def sign_certificate_request(csr_cert, ca_cert, private_ca_key):
    cert = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
        csr_cert.subject
    ).issuer_name(
        ca_cert.subject
    ).public_key(
        csr_cert.public_key()
    ).serial_number(
        x509.random_serial_number()
    ).not_valid_before(
        datetime.utcnow()
    ).not_valid_after(
        # Our certificate will be valid for 10 days
        datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=10)
    # Sign our certificate with our private key
    ).sign(private_ca_key, hashes.SHA256())

    # return DER certificate
    return cert.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.DER)
```

- csr_cert is the `cryptography` CSR certificate object - can be loaded from a file with `x509.load_der_x509_csr()`
- ca_cert is the `cryptography` certificate object - can be loaded from a file with `x509.load_pem_x509_certificate()`
- private_ca_key is the `cryptography` private key object - can be loaded from a file with `serialization.load_pem_private_key()`

Comment: It looks to me like the argument to `issuer_name()` should be `ca_cert.subject`, not `ca_cert.issuer`?

Comment: @ErikForsberg You are right. Feel free to update my post as you found the issue :-)