# Can I sign an X509 certificate entirely in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, ssl, x509

I'm working within the Google App Engine (GAE) python 2.7 runtime.

I need sign (and potentially also generate) an X509 certificate (.csr)

I found several [guides](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/64072/OpenSSL.crypto.X509), that rely on [`PyOpenSSL`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27).

As I understand it, PyOpenSSL is is wrapper around OpenSSL and not available in App Engine.
[Pycrypto](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) is available, but does not have a clear pre-built signing method for X509.

**How can I sign an X509 .csr using only python?**

Comment: https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html  might be what you are looking for? ... im not sure if this is the same as x509 ... but it looks like the implementation specs are publicly available so you could implement it... but its gonna be painful

Comment: Does this helps you in any way ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103878/sign-csr-from-client-using-ca-root-certificate-in-python

Comment: Python supports Go lang environment and you can create a module that uses https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/ - and call it via REST API.

Comment: Run the signing code in the flexible runtime and keep that as seperate service that your normal appengine front-ends consume.

Comment: A separate module seems to be the way to go (either in go or a custom runtime).  I'm happy to award a bounty to someone willing to compile the comments into an authoritative answer.

Comment: Looking through the GAE docs, it doesn't actually say anywhere that you can't use PyOpenSSL, just that they won't install it for you. Can you not just include the relevant `.so` or `.dll` file somewhere in the `PYTHONPATH` for your project code, and import it from there?

Comment: If not, have a look at [oscrypto](https://github.com/wbond/oscrypto) which claims to to able to do it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12911373/172176

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I sign an X509 certificate entirely in Python?

Almost certainly, but I don't think there are any existing pure Python implementations available. The closest I could find is [`oscrypto`](https://github.com/wbond/oscrypto), but being able to sign an X509 certificate depends on having the `ctypes` module available.

The author has also written a module called [`certbuilder`](https://github.com/wbond/certbuilder), which claims to be a "Python library for generating and signing X.509 certificates", but it depends on the `oscrypto` module.

However, the real question sounds more like...

> Can I sign an X509 certificate on a Google App Engine Python Standard Environment?

In this case, the `oscrypto` module probably won't help, since, according to the docs, the environment doesn't allow usage of the `ctypes` module.

You do have access to the `PyCrypto` module, and although there is [a Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12921889/172176) of reading an X509 certificate using it, and a [C++ example](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/X.509) of verifying an X509 certificate, the Python bindings don't seem to have complete support for encoding and decoding ASN.1. You might be able to combine `PyCrypto` with [`asn1crypto`](https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto) by the same author as `oscrypto` for full ASN.1 support.

If none of these solutions are of any use, then either a [GAE Python Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/) or a [GAE Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/) ought to let you install the `PyOpenSSL` package, but you'd have to contact their tech support team to find out.

Comment: oscrypto will use either ctypes or cffi to call the operating system's crypto library for encryption, decryption, signing and verification. It does not provide pure-Python cryptographic primitives.

Comment: @wbond It seemed unlikely that it would provide a pure Python implementation for signing an X509, but thanks for the confirmation. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I may have found a solution:

[Cryptography.io](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/#creating-a-self-signed-certificate) is entirely python based and even offers a tutorial on how to self sign a cert.

Happy to hear other answers.

Comment: As I dig deeper.. it looks like they rely on OpenSSL as a backend.  I'll leave this answer here as a breadcrum, but at present it looks like this will not work.

Comment: More Breadcrumbs - Looks like M2crypto can do it, but I'm not sure if it relies on OpenSSL  https://gist.github.com/eskil/2338529

Comment: M2Crypto is the most complete Python wrapper for OpenSSL, so no - he rely on openssl too. I'm really don't think, that in the world exists so mad man, which will port openssl to pure python, can't see any sense. In you case, you can create cert sign service on normal host and use him from GAE

Answer (score 1):

That will not be the direct answer, because I never use C and Cython, but maybe it is possible to use some C library for this task.

From [Cython site](http://cython.org/):

> All of this makes Cython the ideal language for wrapping external C
>   libraries, embedding CPython into existing applications, and for fast
>   C modules that speed up the execution of Python code.

Seems like not the simplest and not the best solutions but who is know :)

Comment: Unfortunately, Appengine requires all code to be written in Python, no C code.